# Make bluetooth default for GKSession

Tags: ios, bluetooth, gamekit

I'm developing an iOS app that uses GKSession to connect two devices. GKSession seems to search for a wifi connection by default, then over bluetooth should that fail. I would like to make this the other way around. After a thorough google search the general opinion seems to be this is impossible, which seems silly so I bring this question to stack overflow

PS I have no interest in using GKPeerPickerController because of the interface that comes with it

Thanks in advance to any one who can lend a suggestion to this predicament

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify a connectionTypesMask, for bluetooth only pass in GKPeerPickerConnectionTypeNearby